# Proving that this function is entire

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, entire-functions

This question is from Ponnusamy and silvermann complex analysis Pg 436 .

> Question : Suppose that $0\leq |a_1|\leq  |a_2| \leq |a_3| \ldots \to \infty$. Show that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} ( 1- z/a_n) e^{Q_n(z) }$ represents an entire function with $Q_n(z) = z/a_n + (z/a_n)^2/2 + \ldots + (z/a_n)^{[\ln n]}/[\ln n]$ .

I attempted the question on the same lines as I attempted [Show that This infinite product is entire](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949525/show-that-this-infinite-product-is-entire/3949682#3949682)

When in last step I have to use Weierstrass Theorem, I got the series ${1/a_n}^{[\ln n]+1}$. This series is to be proved convergent. But I am unable to prove it. I am uncertain on which result should I use.

Please help with it. Rest of details of solutions I checked and They are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty E_{\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor}\left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right) $ where $E_n$ are the so-called [elementary factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#The_elementary_factors):
$$
E_{n}(z)=\begin{cases}
(1-z)&{\text{if }}n=0 \, ,\\
(1-z)\exp \left({\frac {z^{1}}{1}}+{\frac {z^{2}}{2}}+\cdots +{\frac {z^{n}}{n}}\right)&{\text{otherwise}} \, .
\end{cases}
$$
The elementary factors satisfy the inequality $|1-E_n(z)| \le |z|^{n+1}$ for $|z| \le 1$.

Now fix $R > 0$ and choose an index $N$ such that $|a_n| > 3R$ for $n \ge N$. Then
$$
\left| 1 -  E_{\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor}\left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right) \right| \le 
\left( \frac 13 \right)^{\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor + 1}
\le \frac{1}{3^{\ln n}} = \frac{1}{n^{\ln 3}}
$$
for $n \ge N$ and $|z| \le R$.

Using the Weierstrass M-test (note that $\ln 3 > 1$) it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 -  E_{\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor}\left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right) \right)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on every disk $|z| \le R$, and that implies that $\prod_{n=1}^\infty E_{\lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor}\left( \frac{z}{a_n}\right) $ converges to a holomorphic function on $\Bbb C$, with zeros exactly at the $a_n$.